# Very basic query on perl

Tags: perl

Write a program to implement Stack operations(push, pop, isEmpty, peek) using an array of string.

I am a beginner on perl and was writing some basic examples. I was able to write push and pop, but I did not find anything related to how to use "isEmpty" and "peek".Please tell me how to use these two!

Comment: You can use arrays as stacks: http://lookatperl.blogspot.ca/2012/11/a-look-at-arrays.html Stings are normally just used for text.

Comment: Are you writing an object-oriented `Stack` class, or just a set of subroutines? Do you realise that Perl already has `push` and `pop`?

Comment: @shawnhcorey : Thanks for the link, its really helpful to learn!
@Borodin : I am just writing a simple 2 line code and printing the output. Yes I am able to get results from `push` and `pop`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

is empty: check the number of elements of the array:

```
my @array = ('this', 'is' , 'an', 'example');
my $is_empty = !@array; # (@array == 0)
```

peek: just take the first element (first check if is not empty):

```
my $peek = $array[0];
```

Comment: Hi @Miguel : Thanks for the answer. I am able to get the `$peek` result, but I am not able to understand the working of `$is_empty`!

Comment: `@array` in scalar context returns the number of elements of that array. If you negate it with the `!` operator, you get a true value if the array is empty

Comment: Could you please tell if the below code is correct for push and pop?`#!/usr/bin/perl
$in=$1;
sub push
{
my $top = 0;
@stack=("a","b","c");
my $max = 20;
print "Push: @stack.";
if($top = $max - 1)
{
print "Overflow";
}
else
{
$stack[$top] = $in;
$top = $top + 1;
print "After Push: @stack.";
}

print "Before Pop: @stack.";
my $new=$stack[$top];
$top = $topi - 1;
print "Poped item: $new.";
print "After Pop: @stack.";
}`